# Force Internet Explorer to ignore cached files

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, caching

How can I have my website force Internet Explorer to ignore any cached files for the site? I'm having an issue with URLs on the site that have a "#" in them. In Chrome, if I go to website.com/#123.htm it will load fine, however if I try in IE it will load website.com/ which is the index of the library/CMS.

I can disable the settings in IE options, but the site (and functionality desired by turning cache off) is used by several hundred users.

I am not having this issue in Chrome and stopped having it when I disabled caching in IE on this computer. On the other note, is it possible to disable cache for certain content and not others (ideally images wouldn't be loaded each time)

My site is using CSS/HTM/JS.

Thanks

Comment: you may add a timestamp to your static files, like `?t=326237835562` to trick the browser that the URL is new; hence, it will load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several headers that can be sent with the response to prevent caching: `Expires: -1`, `Pragma: no-cache`, `Cache-control: no-cache`

If you do not have control over the headers, this can be accomplished with `META` elements, for example:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```